# Чего не выполняются все циклы wile

Tags: python, циклы, while

Вот код

```
while 1 < 2:
     while 1 < 2:
         key_down = input
         valut_kurs = gold / valute
         if key_down == 'курс':
             print(valut_kurs)
     while 1 < 2:
         time.slepp(10)
         random = random.randint(1, 100)
     while 1 < 2:
         time.sleep(120)
         if support < 50:
          print ("ты проиграл ты перестал быть правителем")
     while 1 < 2:
         time.sleep(5)
         support = support - 1
     while 1 < 2:
         time.sleep(60)
         Time = time + 1
     while 1 < 2:
         time.sleep(12)
         gold = gold - 1000/7 * Army
time.sleep(5)
print(gold)
print(valute_kurs)
print(support)
```

Comment: "Чего не выполняются все циклы" - как Вы пришли к такому выводу?

Comment: зато первый хорошо выполняется.

Comment: Как Вы думаете, может ли наступить момент, когда условие `1 < 2` станет ложным? У Вас первый же цикл бесконечный. Но и сама программа довольно странная... Например инструкция `key_down = input` создаст синоним для функции.

Comment: я ожидал что цикл будет выполнятся вечно

Comment: Он и выполняется вечно.

Comment: я думал будут выполнятся несколько циклов одновременно

Comment: В рамках вашей программы это невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Цикл `while 1 < 2` можно приравнять к циклу вида `while true`, и, можно понять, что конца данный цикл иметь не может, пока его не прервет оператор `break`, чего у вас в коде нет. Если же на определенном этапе выполнения программы вы хотите остановить выполнение бесконечного цикла - добавьте в код оператор `break`.